# PyCharm Google-docstring russian language parsing problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, docstring, pep

I've a docstring in some function. This is a google-styled docstring. My PyCharm has enabled default syntax checking.
For some reasons I got a PEP hint, that the first letter in a sentence should be capitalised. But, here is the tricky part. This hint occured under the Arg name.
Here is the screenshot, which illustrates, that different sentence contents affects this situation differently.
[image]
As you can see, I have no hints in `foo`, but I have hint in `foo1`. The only difference is in the content of the previous text line in these functions. And the most important, that the hint says that I need to start every sentence with capital letter. But, in both `foo` and `foo1` we have the dot at the end of the `param1` line.

Here is the code fore testing:

```
def foo(param1: str, param2: int) -> bool:
    """
    Текст, текст, текст.
    Args:
        param1: Некоторый текст, некоторой длины.
        param2: Некоторый текст, некоторой длины.
    Returns:
    """


def foo1(param1: str, param2: int) -> bool:
    """
    Текст, текст, текст.
    Args:
        param1: Некоторый текст, некоторой длины текст.
        param2: Некоторый текст, некоторой длины.
    Returns: None
    """
```

I've tried to reproduce it in english, but I didn't obtain any result.
What causes such irrational behaviour?

My specs:
PyCharm 2023.1.5 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-231.9414.12, built on February 14, 2024

**UPD**: Here is the hint example:

[image]
It says "this sentence does not start with a capital letter"

Comment: when you hoover your mouse pointer over `param2` in `foo1` example, what the popup message say?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it says that "this sentence does not start with a capital letter" (may be it is not 100% accurate to the original, but in russian it sound like this). In addition it gives some examples, like: [Correct: "Hello. How are you?" Incorrect: "Hello. how are you"]. I've attached an example to the question body.

Comment: I'd report this as a bug to JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code into PyCharm running on my machine (MacBook Pro M1 2020 - Sonoma 14.4), and I didn't get a PEP hint.

I'm running:
PyCharm 2023.3.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-233.13763.11, built on January 25, 2024

[image: PyCharm Professional - No PEP hint for non-capitalized word in docstring]

Maybe try updating PyCharm to the latest version? (unless you're already running the most recent update).

Comment: This is strange. I think something with my cache or this is just an "ordinary" windows "feature" bc I use the latest available version (Build #PC-231.9414.12, built on February 14, 2024)